# Process Id and UID

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator

Is it possible to programatically set same process id and shared uid for two different applications instead of setting it in manifest file? If so, please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This is all controlled by the manifest as part of the security model. If you could change your user_id or process_id programatically none of the security mechanisms would work.